# Help with building a tezos-client from sources (from scratch)

Tags: tezos-client

I'm trying to install that to build a tezos-client from scratch

```
logart@logart2:~$ sudo sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)
sh: 0: Can't open /dev/fd/63
```

Any idea on how to fix that?
Why is saying it can't open that?
I would appreciate any help

Comment: It does not seem to be an error related to the Tezos installation. What is your setup?
Have you had a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279545/failed-to-open-config-file-dev-fd-63-error-no-such-file-or-directory-for-wp?

Comment: I tried 
sudo su -c sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh) 

Then it asked me for the password and it outputs this:

No passwd entry for user '/dev/fd/63'

Comment: I tried sudo su -c sh <(curl -sL raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh) Then it asked me for the password and it outputs this: No passwd entry for user '/dev/fd/63'

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split up the process in 2 step to see where the error is:

```
curl -L -o install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh
sh ./install.sh
sudo sh ./install.sh             # If the above complains about access rights
```